# Can SuperSearch use Matrix fields in {excerpt}?

Tags: matrix, supersearch

I am using SuperSearch with "Use Smart Excerpts?" set to "Yes", and a Matrix field with "Is field searchable?" set to "Yes". My search results contain pages with matrix field content as expected. However, the contents of the Matrix fields do not appear in the {excerpt} output. Is there a way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Each channel has its own setting for the field used by {excerpt} under *Admin > Channels > Edit Preferences > Which field should be used for search excerpt?*. Matrix field types can be selected and used like any other type.

However, using a Matrix field here does give erratic results compared to a textfield. The excerpt sometimes starts with the search term, truncating content before it. Other times it makes no truncation and just prints the first X characters of all tabs combined instead, even if they don’t include the search term. Sometimes it doesn't bold the search term.